# iOS - AFNetworking - Understanding this code snippet- whats it doing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, afnetworking

Im trying to understand some code I found on the internet. Im trying to tweak it so I can use it in my own program. In my program Ive made this a instance method of a singleton. I understand most of what this is doing but dont get the "block" part. What is the block for? and in my implementation, what should I pass as the parameter in place of NSSet Photos. I dont understand this since, Im actually hoping to "get" photos from the server for that location. So what am I sending ?

```
 + (void)photosNearLocation:(CLLocation *)location
                 block:(void (^)(NSSet *photos, NSError *error))block
 {
    NSLog(@"photosNearLocation - Photo.m");
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mutableParameters setObject:[NSNumber 
    numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"lat"];
    [mutableParameters setObject:[NSNumber 
    numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"lng"];

    [[GeoPhotoAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/photos"
                               parameters:mutableParameters
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON)
    {
      NSMutableSet *mutablePhotos = [NSMutableSet set];
      NSLog(@" Json value received is : %@ ",[JSON description]);
      for (NSDictionary *attributes in [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"photos"])
      {
        Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc]
                        initWithAttributes:attributes];
        [mutablePhotos addObject:photo];
      }

      if (block) {
        block([NSSet setWithSet:mutablePhotos], nil);
       }
     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
       if (block)
      {
        block(nil, error);
        NSLog(@"Error in Photo.m line 145 %@ ", [error description]);
       }
      }];
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass anything for the photo set.  It's a parameter to the block.  The caller's job is to pass a block that will be invoked when the method finishes some asynchronous work.  So you'd call it like this:

```
// let's setup something in the caller's context to display the result
// and to demonstrate how the block is a closure - it remembers the variables
// in it's scope, even after the calling function is popped from the stack.

UIImageView *myImageView = /* an image view in the current calling context */;

[mySingleton photosNearLocation:^(NSSet *photos, NSError *error) {
    // the photo's near location will complete some time later
    // it will cause this block to get invoked, presumably passing
    // a set of photos, or nil and an error
    // the great thing about the block is that it can refer to the caller context
    // as follows....

    if (photos && [photos count]) {
        myImageView.image = [photos anyObject];   // yay.  it worked
    } else {
        NSLog(@"there was an error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. A further question I have is, isn't there already code in the original function to handle the success and failure of the return call? If thats correct then do I need to add the code like in your example outside of the function in the caller's method to  handle the block? This is whats confusing me. Who handles the block, the caller or the singleton?

Comment: It looks like upon success, the method passes the result to the block.  On failure, it logs the error and calls the block with nil and the error.  If that's all you need done, then you can just pass an empty block - which is like an empty method (NSSet *set, NSError *error) ^{}.  But presumably, you're calling it because you want to do something with those images, like save them or present them (or the error) to the user.  That's what you'd put in the block.